# Use of Whither and Whence

Tags: grammar, formal-language, archaic-language

Could you check the following sentences:

*You should be concerned with where you are going to.*

*You should be concerned with whither you are going.*

---

*Where all those refugees came from?*

*Whence all those refugees came?*

What is the difference between them? I mean, yes, the latter sentence is much of a Shakespeare style, it is used mostly in poems or/and literature but can I use them while inditing a very formal piece?

Comment: 'Where did all those refugees come from/Whence did all those refugees come?' would be better, but I would advise you not to use _whither_ or _whence_ in modern language.

Comment: In some languages, dated words are sometimes used to talk in the most formal register. However, I don’t think this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Both *where* and *whence*/*whither* talk about places.

*Whence* is used when the place is a source or starting point.  *Whither* is used when the place is a destination or ending point.

*Where* is used when the place is simply something we're communicating and isn't part of a motion.

Or:

- *Whence* is basically equivalent to *from where*.
- *Whither* is basically equivalent to *to where*.

> I mean, yes, the latter sentence is much of a Shakespeare style, it is used mostly in poems or/and literature but can I use them while inditing a very formal piece?

Avoid using these words unless you are quoting old literature.